# What is the error in the piece of code from codeacademy

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code, I get an error: `TypeError: Object [object Object]`

```
// create your Animal class here

function Animal(name, numLegs)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}

// create the sayName method for Animal

Animal.prototype = function sayName()
{
    console.log("Hi, my name is [name]");
};
// provided code to test above constructor and method
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

Why?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sayName'

Comment: Is that really copied straight out of a Codeacademy lesson? You should pass on the fact that it's erroneous.

Comment: Is this like where you have to find the error? or something

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the problem

```
   Animal.prototype = function sayName(){

     console.log("Hi, my name is [name]");

   };
```

should be

```
   Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){

     console.log("Hi, my name is ", this.name);

   };
```

Also `[name]` is not javascript :S

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48cGJ/1/)

Comment: This is correct but note that the animal name won't be logged.

Comment: Didn't notice that part Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The Animal prototype is set up incorrectly:

```
Animal.prototype = {
  sayName: function() {
    console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
  }
};
```

Setting up the prototype as a function isn't completely wrong, but the problem is the code intends to use a property called "sayName" on the prototype object. Providing a function named "sayName" will not work for that purpose; that name isn't exposed as a property of the function object.

Also note that simply putting "[name]" in the string logged to the console will not cause the animal name to be logged. You've got to explicitly patch it into the string from the "name" property of the object, as in the code I posted.