# Inheritance codecademy tutorial on javascript

Tags: javascript

> Let's say we're dealing with a lot of Penguins. It sure would be nice to create a Penguin class so that perhaps later we can give it some methods unique to a penguin and not confuse it with the Animal class.
>
> #### Instructions
>
> Create a new Penguin class constructor. A penguin is an animal so it should also have the name and numLegs properties as well as a sayName method that prints the same thing as Animal's sayName method.
>
> We're not done with animals yet, so we have still included the Animal constructor and its sayName method. The last two lines test your Penguin code.

Where have I gone wrong in my code?

```
                  function Animal(name, numLegs) {
                    this.name = name;
                  this.numLegs = numLegs;
                      }
                     Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
                     console.log("Hi my name is "+this.name);
                };

            // create a Penguin constructor here

                  var penguin = new Penguin(name,numLegs);
                 function sayName(){

                 console.log("Hi, this is" + this.name);
                  };

                  // create a sayName method for Penguins here


                   // our test code
                   var theCaptain = new Penguin("Captain Cook", 2);
                  theCaptain.sayName();
                  var penguin = new Penguin("captain1",54)
```

Comment: What does it not do that it should, or do that it should not?

Comment: Hi @RtrRtr! Stack Overflow isn’t designed for code mentoring — questions are meant to describe, with detail, a problem that you’ve encountered, so that other people encountering the same problem can benefit from the question and its answers later. Could you describe what you expect your code to do, and what it actually does? (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the error in the piece of code from codeacademy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630542/what-is-the-error-in-the-piece-of-code-from-codeacademy)

Comment: We’re also not here to act as free personal Codecademy tutors.

Comment: alright i am not blind, i read your first message.

Comment: As i remember codeCademy have their own Q&A, so... http://www.codecademy.com/forums/objects-ii/3

Comment: and if you want to create Penguin constructor take a look at Animal constructor... The only thing that you have to change is name of constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what the exercise is asking for, but this is how I would do it:

```
function Penguin () {
    Animal.apply(this, arguments);   
}
Penguin.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Penguin.prototype.constructor = Penguin;
```

The above code makes *Penguin* instances inherit from *Animal* (the `sayName` method). Also, the *Animal* constructor is used to set up the own properties of *Penguin* instances (the name and number of legs).

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code for the exercise:

```
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
                    this.name = name;
                  this.numLegs = numLegs;
                      }
                     Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
                     console.log("Hi my name is "+this.name);
                };

            // create a Penguin constructor here

                function Penguin(name, numLegs) {
                    this.name = name;
                  this.numLegs = numLegs;
                      }
                     Penguin.prototype.sayName = function() {
                     console.log("Hi my name is "+this.name);
                };
// provided code to test above constructor and method
var penguin = new Penguin("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```